# Neo4J Community 4.1.6 Stops after starting

Tags: neo4j

I try to run Neo4J Community Edition 4.1.6 and need a hint. I have downloaded the winzip-package and unzipped it on a Windows 10 PC. I created a folder for the Neo4j files and another for the current JDK 15 package. The path for JDK has been put into system path variables. The log-flags in the neo4j conf has been set to DEBUG for HTPP. JAVA version throws the correct "15.0.2". No JAVA error message while starting.

I can start the service and the status gives back "Neo4j Service started...". After roughly 10 seconds the status shows that Neo4j has stopped without any further notice.

I can't see any logs in the \logs folder - the folder is empty.
I do not see a graphdb been created under neo4j-community-4.1.6\data\databases - the folder is empty
I cannot access the DB by localhost:7474

I do not see any error messages in the cmd windows.

I restarted the system several times but I still have the same outcome. Any hints?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we only support JDK 11 when using Neo4j 4.x.

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/requirements/#deployment-requirements-java

Your errors may be because you are using JDK 15.

When diagnosing issues, it also helps to check the neo4j.log and debug.log files in the logs directory.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I will try this. Regarding the logs: The issue is as written there are no logs. So it's hard to debug.